# My filter does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Im trying to change my status value from numbers to 'text'

I wonder how i can solve it, and what i did wrong? Thank you in advance

```
      <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in Id">
                <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.status | status}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

When i write the | status <- it crashes the whole ng repeat and nothing displays.

```
    var app = angular.module('customersController', []);

    function customersController($scope, $http) {

     $http.get("localhost")
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.Id = response;

            });

    app.filter('status', function () {
        return function (input) {
            var statu;
            switch (input) {
                case 10:
                    statu = 'Bronze';
                    break;
                case 20:
                    statu = 'Silver';
                    break;
                case 30:
                    statu = 'Gold';
                    break;
                case 40:
                    statu = 'Elite';
                    break;

            }

            return statu;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Should it not be `return statu` instead of point?

Comment: Sorry i missed that, but still not working

Comment: Open the console, any errors?

Comment: What is being returned in `response`?

Comment: nothing is being returned in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a filter inside a controller. That is not valid. You may only add filters to a module during the configuration phase, before the app is started and the controller is instantiated. The code should be:

```
var app = angular.module('customersController', []);
app.filter('status', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var statu;
        switch (input) {
            case 10:
                statu = 'Bronze';
                break;
            case 20:
                statu = 'Silver';
                break;
            case 30:
                statu = 'Gold';
                break;
            case 40:
                statu = 'Elite';
                break;
        }
        return statu;
    };
});

app.controller('customersController', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("localhost")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.Id = response;
        });
});
```

Comment: i uploaded the plunker

Comment: No, you didn't. You may not have `<script>` tags in JS files. `<script>` tags go in HTML files. And your HTML file doesn't have any ng-app, and doesn't use your controller. Also, what do you expect `$http.get("localhost")`to do?

Comment: reason why i got <script> is becouse its in my html file, and on body i have 
<body ng-app> ,and my httpget localhost is working, its loading my json file, but still i did like you said, but its not working

Comment: yeah i missed give my ngapp a name in body, and then put it in angularmodule. its working now, thank you for ur help